# How to integrate $\int \cos^2(3x)dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\int \cos^2(3x)dx$$

The answer according to my instructor is:

$${1 + \cos(6x) \over 2} + C$$

But my book says that:

$$\int \cos^2(ax)dx = {x \over 2} + {\sin(2ax) \over 4a} + C$$

I'm not really sure which one is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your instructor (hopefully) meant is that you need to use $$\cos^2(3x) = {1 + \cos(6x) \over 2},$$

which is a specialization of the trig identity $$\cos^2(x) = {1 + \cos(2x) \over 2}.$$

Using this identity we can integrate $$\int \cos^2(3x) dx = \int{1 + \cos(6x) \over 2} dx$$ to get the  answer from the book.

Comment: Ok now I see that is what he meant thanks

Comment: I think a square is missing in the identity.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods you can use. Integration by parts and solving for the integral, or the half angle formula.

Remember that the half angle formula is given by $\cos^2(x) = \frac12 (1+\cos(2x))$ and also $\sin^2(x) = \frac12(1-\cos(2x))$.

Thus $$\int \cos^2(3x) dx = \frac12 \int (1+\cos(6x)) dx = \frac12 \left(x + \frac{\sin(6x)}{6}\right) + C.$$

---

The method of using integration by parts goes like this (I am changing $\cos(3x)$ to $\cos(x)$ for this example).

$$\int \cos^2(x) dx = \cos(x)\sin(x) + \int \sin^2(x) dx$$ we used $u=\cos(x)$ and $dv = \cos(x)dx$. Now using the pythagorean identity we have:

$$\int \cos^2(x) dx = \cos(x)\sin(x) + \int (1-\cos^2(x)) dx$$

Which leads to:

$$2 \int \cos^2(x) dx =\cos(x)\sin(x) + \int 1 dx.$$

So we have:

$$\int \cos^2(x) dx = \frac12 \left( x + \cos(x)\sin(x) \right) +C.$$

Finally using the double angle formula for $\sin(x)$ we have:

$$\int \cos^2(x) dx = \frac12 \left( x + \frac{\sin(2x)}{2} \right) +C.$$

This is the form we would find if we used the half angle formula.

Answer (score 1):

What your instructor told you is $\cos^2(ax) = \frac{1+\cos(2ax)}{2}$ ([half angle formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-AngleFormulas.html)), then you can integrate it easily.